# jquery call from button codebehind asp.net

Tags: jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('.popup').hide();
            overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
            return false;
        });

    $('.x').click(function () {
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
    });

    $('.click').click(function () {
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

how to call jquery  .click function from codebehind c#?`ryenter code here function from code behind file in asp.net

Comment: Did you read your question again? `:)`

Comment: hi, i want to call this jquery function from codebehind file while button click  $('.click').click(function () {
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        return false;
    });

Comment: Okay, the code seems to do what you wanna do.

Comment: just alert box..if we click button then some codes need to be processed in codebehind and finally this jquery function calls to show "password changed successfully" alert..

Comment: hi praveen Ji did you understand?

Comment: No macha... Still confusing... Waiting to understand.

Comment: $('.click').click(function () {
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        return false;
    });      i want to call this function when i click button..

Comment: machi i have not used script manager.. just inside javascript i wrote that jquery function

Comment: Ah Script Manager? Apdina? I am not so good with C# da. So let's wait for some C# geniuses to answer. `:)`

Comment: i try this but not working protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "$(function() {$('.click' ).click(); });", true);      
        }
        }

Comment: Suresh, I am not sure about C#. Let's wait for other answers. Thanks.

Comment: ok fine thanks..lets try